# Поиск и сложение элементов в map и vector

Tags: c++, vector, map, вектор, поток-ввода

В коде нужно, чтобы цена на один и тот же товар, для одного и того же покупателя складывалась.

Например, при вводимых данных такого вида:

```
Ivanov paper 10
Petrov pens 5
Ivanov marker 3
Ivanov paper 7
Petrov envelope 20
Ivanov envelope 5
```

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
Ivanov:
envelope 5
marker 3
paper 17
Petrov:
envelope 20
pens 5
```

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
struct item {
    string name;
    int price;
};
 
int main (void) {
    map <string, vector <item>> s;
    string key, name;   int price;
 
    cout << "input:" << endl;
    while (cin >> key >> name >> price)
        s[key].push_back({name, price});
 
    cout << endl;
    for (auto n : s)
        for (auto i : n.second)
            cout << n.first << " " << i.name << ": " << i.price << endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: опишите проблему, с которой столкнулись, в вопросе

Comment: Ну хоть немного уважайте отвечающих - из вашего т.н. вопроса невозможно ничего понять...

Comment: Не понимаю как в <item> где string (к примеру название товара) и int (цена) сложить ту самую цену товара, и все это находится в 
map <string, vector <item>> s

Comment: Сложить все цены для одного покупателя, для всех? Для конкретных товаров? Впрочем, мне можете не отвечать - увы, сегодня у меня просто нет времени :(

Comment: Покупатель предмет 4
Покупатель предмет 2

вывод
Покупатель: 
предмет 6

Comment: Сложить и просто напечатать? Или поместить обратно в карту куда-то?

Comment: Сложить и напечатать

Comment: С минимальными изменениями: заведите переменную `sum`, в которую складываете `i.price`

Comment: Судя по всему вам лучше всего использовать map<string, map<string, int>>

Answer (score 1):

Предложу свою версию кода с использованием `map<string, map<string, int>>`. Условимся, что конец ввода на три нуля, а то эти споры про ввод никогда не утихнут.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
 
int main () 
{
    map <string, map<string, int>> s;
    string key, name;   
    int price;
 
    cout << "input:" << endl;
    while (cin >> key >> name >> price)
    {
        if (key == "0" && name == "0" && price == 0)
            break;
        s[key][name] += price;
    }
 
    cout << endl;
    for (pair<string, map<string, int>> pers : s)
    {
        cout << pers.first << ":\n";
        for (pair<string, int> item : pers.second)
            cout << item.first << " " << item.second << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы сложить цены введенных товаров, их надо искать в векторе, сравнивая наименования (name) в структурах, а если ничего не найдено, то добавлять новую позицию (структуру `item`) в вектор:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
struct item {
    string name;
    int price;
};
 
int main (void) {
    map <string, vector <item>> s;
    string key, name;   int price;
 
    cout << "input:" << endl;
    while (cin >> key ) {
        // Разбил ваш cin, иначе не ясно как вы выскакиваете из цикла ввода позиций
        // Если введен q, то выходим из ввода позиций 
        if ( key == "q" ) 
            break;

        cin >> name >> price;

        // флаг найденной позиции в векторе
        bool flag = false;
        for( int i = 0; i < s[key].size(); i++)
            if ( s[key][i].name == name ) {
                // Нашли позицию - складываем цену
                s[key][i].price += price;
                flag = true;
                break;
            }            
        // Если позиция не была найдена, то добавляем ее в вектор
        if ( !flag )            
            s[key].push_back({name, price});
    }
 
    cout << endl;
    for (auto n : s)
        for (auto i : n.second)
            cout << n.first << " " << i.name << ": " << i.price << endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Огромная благодарность....
спасибо за помощь, теперь все отлично, долго не мог разобраться

Comment: лучше сортировать вектор, чтобы  для каждого поиска не перебирать весь вектор